# Can log as admin but dashboard missing

Tags: wp-admin

I have a problem with the admin dashboard. I can login as admin, but don't have access to the dashboard. Only getting the admin bar at the top. It happens after migrating a site from local to the server. Flywheel is used as a local environment. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd first make sure that the wp-options table has your new URL - in both places.

Then I would look at the error log to see what error is causing the 'almost-white-screen-of-death'. That will provide you with a  direction to start. "White screens of death" are almost always caused by a fatal PHP error.

Make sure the production system has the proper (current) PHP version - recommend version 7.x. Maybe a deprecated function is causing an error.

And if you have moved media also, then each of the media entries will need to have their URL updated. I use a search and replace plugin ("Better Search and Replace" is my favorite; there are others) to change all URLs (site-wide) from the development URL to the production URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think Rick's answer is a good place to start. How did you migrate the database? Also, if you can on production, add the following to your `wp-config.php`, just before the line for including `wp-settings.php`:

```php
 80 define('WP_DEBUG', true);
 81 define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', WP_DEBUG);
 82 define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', WP_DEBUG);
 83  
 84 /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
 85  
 86 /** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
 87 if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 88     define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
 89  
 90 /** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
 91 require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

The relevant lines here are the `WP_DEBUG*` lines - this will do a couple of things:

- `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` - enables debugging from WordPress
- `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', WP_DEBUG);` - enables/disables logging debug messages based on the value of `WP_DEBUG`
- `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY`, WP_DEBUG);`- enables/disables displaying debug messages on the site - you may want to change the value from`WP_DEBUG`to`false`if you're worried about potential visitors seeing debug information, i.e.`define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);`

Of particular help may be the second line there - `WP_DEBUG_LOG`, when set to `true`, will log PHP errors to `wp-content/debug.log`. Turn on `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG`, visit your admin area, and then check your server for `wp-content/debug.log` - you should now see any relevant errors or warnings that are logged by WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys a lot, but I already did that steps. I can't access dashboard so Better Search Replace plugin is useless. I used Searced Replace DB for that, but the [image]problem is still there.